# Finding speed from a vector, parametization of its tangent line at a point

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have the following questions on my homework problem, and I've gotten the first part wrong. Since I think I need part a) to figure out subsequent parts, I'm hoping that if you can help me get a), I can figure out c) and d) with minimal help.

The problem as copied from my homework:

The position vector for a particle moving on a helix is $c(t) = (3 cos(t), 5 sin(t), t^2)$.

a) Find the speed of the particle at time $t_0 = 4π$

b) Is $c'(t)$ ever orthogonal to $c(t)$?

c) Find a parametrization for the tangent line to $c(t)$ at $t_0 = 4π.$ (Enter your answer as a comma-separated list of equations in $(x, y, z)$ coordinates.)

d) Where will this line intersect the xy-plane?

For part a), I get $c'(t)=(-3\sin(t),5\cos(t),2t)$, which means $c'(4\pi)=(0, 5, 8\pi)$. However, the software flags it as incorrect, and I am confused on why.

I guessed part for part b), and got it wrong. Why is $c'(t)$ orthogonal to $c(t)$ at $0$, and not multiples of $\pi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

speed $= \|c'(t)\|$

based on your work, speed is $\sqrt {5^2 + (8\pi)^2}$

b) the most direct way would be to find the dot product $c(t)\cdot c'(t)$ and $c'(t)$  is orthogonal to $c(t)$ if and only if the dot product is 0.

If you want to be more abstract about it.  If $\|c(t)\|$ is constant, it is (at least momentarily), traveling in a circular path about the origin, and $c'(t)$ must be orthogonal.

c)

$L = c'(t)s + c(t)$ is the line tangent to the curve at any time $t.$

d) find $s$ such that the z-coordinate in $L$ above $= 0$  What are the $x,y$ coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you on the velocity vector.  But as Doug M points out, speed is not the same thing.  Speed is the magnitude of velocity, or the length of the velocity vector.

As for (b), notice
$$
   c(t) \cdot c'(t) = 16\cos t\sin t + 2t^3
$$
This is zero when $t=0$, but not any other multiple of $\pi$.  It's hard to show this analytically, but with a graph you can see it's only zero at $t=0$.

Comment: regarding a), speed is not the same thing as velocity.

Comment: @DougM: You're right; I'll edit.